# Why doesn't Pop_OS! show "Install alongside Windows" option even when I have unallocated space?

Tags: windows, dual-boot

I have unallocated space on my SSD which I plan to use to install Pop_OS! When I boot from the live USB to install it, I am presented with only 2 options - clean install (wipe disk) or advanced install (create partition layouts manually).

My current partitioning looks like the following:

[image]

Some further investigation:

**1. Gparted**:
Running GParted on my live USB shows me unallocated space similar to the image above.

**2. Dynamic vs Basic Disk:**
I'd read on various Unix.SE answers that dynamic disks cannot be used to dual-boot any Linux distro. When I right click my disk on "Disk 0", it gives me an option to "Convert to Dynamic Disk". Additionally, it says "Basic" on the screenshot itself.

So I have the following questions:

1. Given that it's a basic disk with unallocated partition that GParted also shows, why doesn't the Pop_OS! installer
   provide installing alongside Windows as an option?
2. Given that I have a GPT SSD, is it safe to create partitions from the unallocated space manually or would it wipe out the entire disk and take Windows installation with it?

Comment: Does it give an option to install in free space?  What options is the installer giving you?

Comment: @Oskar Skog Clean Install, Advanced install (create partitions yourself)

Comment: I am not familiar with Pop OS installer but it should be fine creating the partitions yourself.

Comment: @Rayleigh I answered my own question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I booted a live USB with Ubuntu 20.04 and had the option to install alongside Windows Boot Loader. The Pop_OS! installer does not have the option to install alongside - you either do a clean install or make partitions yourself.